# Microsoft Bot Framework Special Characters

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, chatbot

A coworker of mine developed a bot using MS Bot Framework. It's working as expected, but there are responses wherein special characters are shown in place of apostrophe's. Please let me know if you guys experienced this and have any fix. Thanks. :)

[image: Sample Response]

Comment: That looks like a character encoding issue but it's hard to say without knowing a little more. Can you provide details and code samples?

Comment: I thought it was as well, but I just updated the script, and it seems to be working fine now. Thanks for the input though. :)

Comment: I expect that was a `’` rather than a `'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex class for a best practice to avoid other special characters in future. Below is the sample you can use

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        string inputString = "Manoj# Bhard@waj";
        //  . indicates any character to be removed. You can also write characters as well to remove some selected characters
        string outputString = Regex.Replace(input, ".", " ");

        // Write the output.
        Console.WriteLine(inputString);
        Console.WriteLine(outputString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue, then I created the message with below formats in MS bot Code(app.js).

```
var customMessage = new builder.Message(session)
        .text("I didn't quite get that. For us ......")
        .textFormat("plain")
        .textLocale("en-us");
    session.send(customMessage);
```

Refer Official URL for V3: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-message-create?view=azure-bot-service-3.0